# Catch errors with window.onerror yet see errors on console

Tags: javascript, dom-events

My web page is catching errors with `window.onerror` and than sends the error to the server for logging. This is working well. However, I stopped seeing the errors on Chrome and Firefox console logs. This makes debugging the application more difficult. Is there any way I can keep using `window.onerror` yet see the error logs on the console without writing it myself on the `onerror`? When Chrome is writing the error to the console (if `onerror` is not used) the stacktrace and navigation to the error source are really helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to return `false` at the end of the error handler to let the default error handler (which logs to the console) run.

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
  //Do some of your ajax requests or whatever  

  return false;
}
```

Out of MDN:

> When the function returns true, this prevents the firing of the
>   default event handler.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror