# Angular directive for contingent background image

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want a directive that sets the background image to a specific image, if it exists, or to a default one.

`url` takes the form `/images/cards/card{{$index}}.jpg` from an `ng-repeat`, but only some of the images actually exist.

This does it, but the failed `$http` requests are being logged to the console which I don't want (as the whole point of this code is to be aware that some images don't exist).  Any advice? (It seems that an`<img>` tag has an error event that can be trapped, but I can't find evidence `background-image` has one too.

```
angular.module("stickers")
.directive('bkgDiv', function($http) {
    return {
        scope: {
            url: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // console.log("bkgDiv", scope.url);
            $http.get(scope.url)
            .success(function() {
                elem.css({backgroundImage: "url("+scope.url+")"});
            })
            .error(function() {
                elem.css({backgroundImage: "url(/images/animal.png)"});
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd tell you to make sure `scope.url` is not null, but I don't know your code.  Is there a possibility `scope.url` will not be null and not point to a valid image url?

Comment: @MotiAzu indeed, `scope.url` will often not point to a valid url - have updated question

Comment: Perhaps this will work ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073026/catch-errors-with-window-onerror-yet-see-errors-on-console

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192464/window-onerror-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113286/prevent-http-errors-from-being-logged-in-browser-console window.error might be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you'd establish another field at the same level as the image url and you'd test for its existence then, storing result in a Boolean (as far as JS does Booleans).  That way you can bind to this new Boolean in your view.